# How can I read a text file that is being edited by another program in Java?

Tags: java, text-files

So I need to be able to read a .txt file that is being edited by another program. Basically what's going on is I have another program that is logging data from a sensor and storing that info onto a .txt file in real time. I want to be able to read the .txt file and use the info stored while the other program is continually logging new info. All I need to know is if this is possible and a general pointer to any libraries or methods I should use. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only read a file which is not locked. On Windows, files are locked by default.  On Linux, file are not locked by default.

In short, use Linux if you really need to do this.  If you do you don't need to do anything special in terms of libraries.

If you use Windows, the other program needs to periodically close or release the file so you can read it.

Comment: What does it mean to have a file be locked? 

So does this mean its impossible to read from a file open in another program? If this is true, then wouldn't it be impossible to open 2 copies of the same Microsoft Word document? yet we can still do it.. What I'm wondering is how is this accomplished in Java?

Thank you so much for your answer! I'm sorry I'm very new to reading and writing files from Java..

Comment: @JaredZhao Windows locks all open file by default.  This is a feature of the operating system to prevent concurrent access to a file.  You must have seen situations where some one else is use a file and you can't access it until they close it. It is impossible for two users to open a file at the same time in Windows.

Comment: So essentially what you are saying is that if I install Linux rather than Windows, I will be able to accomplish this?

Also, if this file is stored on Google Drive or a similar cloud service, will there be the same problem if I were to continue using windows? 

Thanks! This has been very helpful!

Comment: @JaredZhao Google drive cannot access the file while it is open for the same reason. It will only synchronise the file when you are not using it.